# How can I install php5-curl on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64)

Tags: apt, linux-kernel, php, curl

I have a working server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-generic x86_64), including apache and php.  Now I want to add curl support for php by running this:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
```

Sounds simple?  No.  I get this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-26-generic but it is not going to be installed
 php5-curl : Depends: libcurl3 (>= 7.16.2-1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4) but 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

It looks like I have to upgrade to a new kernel (3.2.0-26) just to get php-curl working.  I would prefer to not have to do this.

Is there some way I can install php curl for my kernel version which is 3.2.0-24?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

I had thought that it simply wanted to upgrade the kernel.  It turns out that there was actually a real problem with dependencies, which occurred as a result of the partition running out of space.  After a bit of deleting, I found some more space and installed the new kernel.  Now everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

I read this on your question:

```
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

> One of the most basic fixes to resolve dependencies problems is to
>   run:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```
>
> The -f hare stands for “fix broken”. Apt will attempt to correct
>   broken dependencies. If you manually installed a package that had
>   unmet dependencies, apt-get will install those dependencies, if
>   possible, otherwise it may simply remove the package that you
>   installed in order to resolve the problem.

Maybe taking a look to this answer could help you [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: When I try running that, it wants to install linux-image-3.2.0-31-generic, among others.  I think this would upgrade to a new kernel, which is exactly what I was hoping to avoid.  But I'll consider it if there are no other alternatives.